# Growl like notifications in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, growl, notice

Has anyone heard of a library to achieve such an effect in flex apps ?

Otherwise it just be a simple panel with some skinning, fading effect and a timer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Flex 4 notification framework for web apps. You can check it out here http://www.blog.tylerchesley.org/2009/08/08/bark-growl-like-notifications-for-flex/

Answer (score 1):

This [flex component](http://lukesh.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/rawr-flexgrowl-component-available/) looks decent for flex growl like notifications

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but there is an as3 library that might do what you want called the [as3notificationlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3notificationlib/). It should give you system tray "pop-ups" on Windows and growl like notifications on Mac OS X, don't know what it does on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want real Growl notifications on a Mac in AS3, check out [as3growl](http://code.google.com/p/as3growl/).